# JavaScript: Comparing objects as data structures

Tags: javascript, comparison

I need to do operations like compare that two number arrays have the same values, or two objects have the same member values. Is there a method that does this for me already (either ECMAScript or jQuery)?

For example, the function should return true that these both are the same:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var b = [1,2,3,4];
```

Or with objects, the function should return that these two are the same:

```
var a = { id: 99, name: "Chris" };
var b = { name: "Chris", id: 99 };
```

I'm thinking maybe just `JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)`? Any problem with that?

Comment: Yes, if you've defined `a` and `b` like you have above, stringify will produce `"{"id":99,"name":"Chris"}"`, and `"{"name":"Chris","id":99}"`, which are not equal.

Comment: @zzzzBov: It's worse than that -- the order in which object properties are enumerated is totally undefined by ECMAScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [equiv](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/source/browse/trunk/JsTestDriver/contrib/qunit/equiv.js?r=96) library by Philippe Rathé. (Unfortunately the main site seems to be down, so I linked to js-test-driver source.)

Answer (score 0):

```
function areEquiv ( a, b ) {
  var eqCount = 0,
      sizeCount = 0,
      othCount = 0,
      i;

  if (typeof a.concat === "function") { // if comparing arrays
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      othCount = sizeCount = sizeCount + 1;
      if (a[i] === b[i]) eqCount++;
    }
  } else {                              // if comparing objects
    for (i in a) {
      if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        sizeCount = sizeCount + 1;
        if (a[i] === b[i]) eqCount++;
      }
    }
    for (i in b) {
      if (b.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        othCount = othCount + 1;
      }
    }
  }

  return (a.length == b.length && eqCount == sizeCount && sizeCount == othCount);
}
```

Note that this will only work as long as the array or object contains simple values and isn't an array of objects or object with a parameter that's also an object.

Comment: I think that instead of `a.concat === "function"` it is better to use `if (a instanceof Array) {...}`.
What if someone will add add 'concat()' method to some object?

And yet instanceof takes one or two pointer comparisons (in most of cases) instead of strcmp() as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty silly way to compare two objects containing scalar values:

```
function same(object1, object2) {
    var merged = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
    for (var key in merged) {
        if (!object1.hasOwnProperty(key) || 
            !object2.hasOwnProperty(key) || 
             object1[key] != merged[key]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It relies on jQuery's `extend` and fails if `object2` inherits properties from a prototype, since `extend` copies those, too.